# How to have an unlimited amount of divs shown next to each other

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve the possiblity to have an infinite amount of divs next to each other, but I just don't have an idea at all.

The container div has got a fixed width like this:

```
#container {
    width: 800px;
}
```

Now, the html could look like this

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="div"></div>
    <div class="div"></div>
    <div class="div"></div>
    etc etc etc
</div>
```

How can I achieve this functionability with the use of jQuery if it isn't possible with pure CSS?

I forgot to tell the behaviour of the divs. When there are 2 divs, they should both take 50%, if there are 4, they should take 25%. That's the expected behaviour.

Comment: When you say infinitely are you meaning they will reduce in size depending on the number of divs or can they wrap underneath?

Comment: what is stopping you from putting an unlimited amount of divs in the `#container` and what are you trying to do with `CSS`?

Comment: What does placing divs have to do with jQuery?  And if your container is a fixed width, how can you place "unlimited" numbers of divs next to each other?  Much more information is required.

Comment: It should be noted that at 800 divs, they are each 1 pixel each, your 801st div will not fit, unless you adjust them to 0 pixels in which case, don't do anything and say they are all side by side :)

Comment: @brenjt They will reduce in size is what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkwaU/) for a 99.9% working solution.  You can dynamically calculate the width of the `div` and set them.  However, One the `div` elements become too small, the Math will start breaking, but that's only when the `div`s start becoming smaller than around 13px.  Not sure how small your divs will become.  The interesting part is that this actually doesn't give every `div` exactly the same width because of css rounding.  So what we need to do is take leftover pixels and just evenly distribute them across as many `div`s as possible.

**EDIT** and here is the code

```
var divnum = 0;

function ranColor() {
    var col = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    return col;
}

$("#addDiv").click( function() {
    divnum++;
    $(".container").append("<div id='div"+divnum+"'>"+divnum+"</div>");
    $("#div"+divnum).css("background-color", ranColor());
    var size = $(".container").children().size();
    var width = Math.floor($(".container").width()/size);

    $(".container").children().css("width", width+"px");

    var leftover = ($(".container").width()-width*divnum).toFixed(0);

    while ( leftover > 0 ) {
        var theDiv = $(".container").find("div").eq(leftover%size);
        var divwidth = $(theDiv).width();
        $(theDiv).css("width", divwidth+1);
        leftover--;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, but my divs will eventually even get as small as 3-4px, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: After playing around with it, I finally found the exact answer you want.  Check out my updated solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
   var total = 100;
   var length = $('#container .div').length;
   var percent = total/length+'%';
$('#container .div').each(function(){
   $(this).width(percent);
});
```

Each of the div gets the same % of width

Comment: I can't seem to get this working, but I'm not sure why. This seems like the best solution to me though.

Comment: I was my CSS that bugged me, and it seems to work now! Thank you very much.

Comment: This also won't work after the % gets too small from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DBVts/), which was the first thing I tried as well.

Comment: I found a solution that takes care of the css rounding error, check my answer for the updated fiddle.

Comment: I combined your fiddle and this solution and it works perfectly! Thank you very much, again!

Answer (score 2):

Throw me under the bus if you like, but that sounds awfully like something a table with `table-layout:fixed` is made to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/9stwT/

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
#container {
    /* set a height for further control */
    overflow: auto;
    width: 800px;
}

.div {
    float: left;
    /* set width and margins for spacing */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with pure CSS.  I've added a tiny bit of jQuery just to illustrate that the panels are side-by-side.

**http://jsfiddle.net/2e2PF/**

**HTML**:  (underscore classes purely for decoration)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="panels">
        <div class="panel _p1"></div>
        <div class="panel _p2"></div>
        <div class="panel _p3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#container {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
}
    #panels {
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        width: 20000em;
    }
        .panel {
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            width: 400px;
        }
        ._p1 { background: #FF0000; }
        ._p2 { background: #00FF00; }
        ._p3 { background: #0000FF; }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to give the effect I meant. It just overlays the different divs, but it has to look like an accordion. I would like to thank you for your effort though!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to take into account any spacing applied to each div so something like:

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <style type="text/css">
            #container {width:800px;}
            #container div{border:1px solid; margin:1px; float:left;}
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('#container div').width($('#container').width()/$('#container div').size() - 4 /*you'll have to take into account border and margin*/);
            });
            </script>
            <div id="container">
            <div>&nbsp;t</div><div>&nbsp;t</div><div>&nbsp;t</div>
            </div>
```

Also note that the javascript is triggered once the document is completely loaded by surrounding it in $(function(){/*do stuff here*/});